# Why in Firefox Addon the imported objects can not access the importers' imported modules?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

For clarification, please consider the following simplified example:

**one.js**

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

let obj = {

  init: function() {

   Components.utils.import('chrome://myaddon/modules/two.jsm', this);
  }

  // code here has access to Services.jsm
}
```

**two.js**

```
this.EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ['abc'];

this.abc = {

  // abc is imported into obj()
  // however as part of obj (), abc{} does not have access to Services.jsm
}
```

I know that this is how it works but the question is why?
Result is that for example `Services.jsm` has to be imparted in every module.
Although Firefox caches the modules and there isn't much of a performance difference, I would like to know if the repeated importation can be avoided?

Comment: If modules could access (and therefore make themselves dependent on) values in modules they have been imported to, then the whole module system wouldn't make sense, since the modules wouldn't be isolated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @felix-kling already mentioned, that's due to module level isolation and it makes a lot of sense if you think about it. If it was otherwise not only `Services` would be seen by other modules, but also `abc`.

There is another important reason, though:
Since JS code modules are initiated once and cached after that, what would happen if you imported `two.jsm` twice, once from a module already having imported `Services.jsm` and once from another module not having done so? Now `two.jsm` "seeing" `Services` would depend on which of the other modules was imported first! Which would be extremely nasty.

In that context, your comment about "abc is imported into obj()" is wrong. Your code actually imports `abc` into the top-level scope. `Cu.import` will always import into the top-level scope, unless you explicitly specify another scope to import to.

```
"abc" in this; // false
"abc" in obj; // false
obj.init();
"abc" in this; // true
"abc" in obj; // false!
```

If you wanted to import `two.jsm` into `obj`, you'd need to call `Cu.import` with a second argument.

```
let obj = {
  init: function() {
   Components.utils.import('chrome://myaddon/modules/two.jsm', this);
  }
};
"abc" in this; // false
"abc" in obj; // false
obj.init();
"abc" in this; // false
"abc" in obj; // true
```

But that does not affect the visibility of `Services`, of course.

It would be helpful I guess, if `Cu.import` just auto-imported some modules you'd import anyway, such as `Services.jsm` and `XPCOMUtils.jsm`. But this does not and likely will not ever happen due to legacy reasons and backward-compatibility constraints. (E.g. I had code break that imported `const {Promise} = Cu.import(..., {});` because ES6 added a default `Promise` global...; that kind of backward-compatibility issues/constraints).

#### Alternatives?

Well, the obvious one is not to use `Cu.import` for your own stuff, but use something else. A bunch of add-ons, incl. all SDK add-ons of course, have their own CommonJS-style `require()` implementation.

- You can actually re-use the SDK loader, without using the SDK, or with only using selected parts of the SDK if you like. See the [`loader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/_loader) documentation. I know that Erik creates a loader in the otherwse non-SDK [Scriptish](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish) add-on.
- You can write your own custom loader based on the subscript loader and maybe `Sandbox`. E.g. I did so in my [`extSDK`](https://github.com/nmaier/extsdk/blob/master/loader.jsm) boilerplate (all global symbols in loader.jsm `== loader.jsm::exports` will be visible to each `require`d module).

But doing so may require a quite bit of extra work, extra knowledge, and effort to port existing JS code modules to `require()` based modules.

Comment: Very good ..thanks again Nils... I actually `Cu.import` with scope but I forgot to include it in the code so I will add it for clarity. Anyway, as you said, it is not worth the hassle...but I wanted to understand the process better :)